# Access to zsh_history denied after making zsh default shell

Tags: zsh, command-history

The shell on my Linux device is bash by default. I tried [changing my shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131823/how-to-make-zsh-the-default-shell) to zsh by default.

The only issue is that I can't view my zsh history, and my command history isn't saved to `~/.zsh_history` either.

However, if I manually go to the zsh shell from within bash by typing in `zsh`, I can both view my command history and my command history is saved.

After some troubleshooting, it seems like the issue lies when changing my default shell to zsh. If I do this, I can't access `.zsh_history` anymore:

```
$ cat ~/.zsh_history
cat: /home/user/.zsh_history: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try `chsh -s /bin/zsh YOUR_USER`? How did that not work?

Comment: It didn't work from the root user. I was just able to get it to work by typing `exit` (to switch to the user `user`) and then running the command using `sudo`. The issue persisted though

Comment: Root user? No, no, no, this is about changing _your_ shell. This is all explained in the very post you linked to. You need to run `chsh -s /bin/zsh YOUR_USER` as your regular user and that will change your default shell cleanly.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution. I just needed to set the permissions of the zsh file:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.zsh_history
```

From now on, my history loads and saves correctly.

The issue seems to have been the fact that if I manually change my shell to `zsh` by typing that command in, I get root privileges. If I change the default shell to `zsh`, then I'm logged in as the `user` user.

Comment: No, no, please stop! You are making things worse. Just run `chsh -s /bin/zsh YOUR_USER` and undo any other changes. Please don't use `sudo` blindly. You should _only_ use it when you get a permission denied error.

Comment: Hmm... the problem is that my user *is* root. Whenever I SSH into my Linux machine, it accesses it as the root user.

Comment: WHaaaa? That shouldn't even be possible, that's disabled by default (for good reason). Please stop, take a step back, edit your question and give us all of these details.

Comment: @terdon Also, `chsh -s $(which zsh) root` doesn't return any error but doesn't even work. The only way I can get it to work is by typing in `exit` (which gets me to the `user` user), and then running `chsh -s $(which zsh) user`. But then I start logging in as `user` and not `root` anymore

Comment: That's interesting. It must be my custom Linux distro, HiveOS. It's not really an essential OS and I can always reflash it, so I guess it's not a huge issue if I'm logging in as root or user. But I guess it's funny that they don't use the default behavior of disabling root access...